# Upload libreoffice impress presentation to youtube?

Tags: libreoffice, youtube

I am interested in creating a presentation in Libreoffice Impress, exporting in X format, and uploading it to Youtube with little hassle.

- How do I do this?
- What should X be?
- Have you done this successfully before?

Information: Youtube does not accept `.swf` files, which is an export possibility in LibreOffice Impress. So, the format has to be something else.

Do we have to convert the Libreoffice file to something else that is acceptable to Youtube?

Comment: I don't see any way you could avoid converting to a format supported by youtube, you want to upload it there so you'll need a supported format. What formats does youtube support? Have you considered making a screencast and uploading that?

Comment: I can give you the formats. They are:MOV
.MPEG4
MP4
.AVI
.WMV
.MPEGPS
.FLV
3GPP
WebM; also see https://support.google.com/youtube/troubleshooter/2888402?hl=en . As for a screencast, I suppose this is to "film" the presentation. You can suggest an easy way, but I feel against it on the basis of form. Why run through 3 programs to achieve the goal? It should be Libreoffice and Youtube. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a video from a presentation,  open an screencast recorder, run it in presentation mode and record it. After that, using a video editor you can adjust the video, cutting off the begin and the end. I usually do this and goes right